# FEEL: list contains(inputDataNumberList, 1) with inputDataNumberList= [0,1] returns false

Tags: drools, decision-model-notation

I load this DMN-File in my DMNModel class:

```
<definitions name="DecisionNumberInList" id="def_7e2582e9-cffe-e465-314a-5755eb893319" 
xmlns:ns="http://sample.dmn" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401" 
namespace="http://sample.dmn" exporter="ex" exporterVersion="11" 
xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/MODEL/">
  <itemDefinition name="numberList" id="_75a6eab3-9165-ca7d-c0a9-29c30e583885" isCollection="true">
    <typeRef>number</typeRef>
  </itemDefinition>
  <itemDefinition name="number" id="_92359cdd-befb-b008-9236-57e6da17ec68">
    <typeRef>number</typeRef>
  </itemDefinition>
  <inputData name="inputNumberList" id="_2fb55907-539e-9287-4815-1b08f4139fe5">
    <variable name="inputNumberList" id="_90c33802-4b79-0947-9bd3-335773972551" typeRef="numberList" />
  </inputData>
  <inputData name="inputNumber" id="_e0303644-6ce2-cc1e-7865-f9e4e17d4953">
    <variable name="inputNumber" id="_675cabff-9aee-b0bb-4c2d-30ebbc8c1d0a" typeRef="number" />
  </inputData>
  <decision name="DecisionNumberInList" id="_7e2582e9-cffe-e465-314a-5755eb893319">
    <variable name="DecisionNumberInList" id="_8c8d7a07-d84f-e92a-55b9-6feaea4cfefd" />
    <informationRequirement>
      <requiredInput href="#_2fb55907-539e-9287-4815-1b08f4139fe5" />
    </informationRequirement>
    <informationRequirement>
      <requiredInput href="#_e0303644-6ce2-cc1e-7865-f9e4e17d4953" />
    </informationRequirement>
    <context id="_a62eebec-1312-fda3-f1ec-83bc8d9dc62e">
      <contextEntry>
        <variable name="Result_1_OK" id="_6cf1769c-80d3-3f14-2347-01b7a9844cb3" typeRef="boolean" />
        <literalExpression id="_a724ac61-6930-fecf-900a-f682aba55a79">
          <text>if list contains([0, 1], inputNumber) then true else false</text>
        </literalExpression>
      </contextEntry>
      <contextEntry>
        <variable name="Result_2_OK" id="_ece83e23-fb7c-091a-ad89-54d25458962f" typeRef="boolean" />
        <literalExpression id="_fe8ecb9e-85c1-120d-66b2-84341b46075c">
          <text>if list contains([0, 1], 1) then true else false</text>
        </literalExpression>
      </contextEntry>
      <contextEntry>
        <variable name="Result_3" id="_6243a937-748b-5425-e3a0-7df6c688fbe3" typeRef="boolean" />
        <literalExpression id="_2cf7169f-d6d3-1752-0767-51503cb0a58f">
          <text>if list contains(inputNumberList, inputNumber) then true else false</text>
        </literalExpression>
      </contextEntry>
      <contextEntry>
        <variable name="Result_4" id="_ebc9632c-add4-c133-60e8-aa7ca061121c" typeRef="boolean" />
        <literalExpression id="_1b4a6cbb-340f-6e7f-caf9-70551916d983">
          <text>if list contains(inputNumberList, 1) then true else false</text>
        </literalExpression>
      </contextEntry>
    </context>
  </decision>
</definitions>
```

Then I call:
`DMNResult result = dmnRuntime.evaluateAll(dmnModel, context);`
with context:
[inputNumberList [0, 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yujp.png)

and get the result:

```
Result_1_OK=true,
Result_2_OK=true,
Result_3=false,
Result_4=false
```

**What am I doing wrong with Result_3 and Result_4 or why does the evaluation not find the number in the list?**

With string lists or boolean lists all goes right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting, this was a bug and we just [fixed it](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4679).

As a workaround, you can supply to the API a `List<BigDecimal>` and that should avoid the problem.
Anyhow my best advice is to avoid the workaround if possible, and either cherry-pick the fix or update as soon as a new Drools version is released containing the mentioned fix.